# Where is a file stored in .documentDirectory?

Tags: ios, swift, file, path

I wrote a file in `.documentDirectory` in `.userDomainMask`:

```
do {
  let fileManager = FileManager.default
  let docs = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                 in: .userDomainMask,
                                 appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
  let path = docs.appendingPathComponent("myName.txt")
  let data = "Hai...!".data(using: .utf8)!
  fileManager.createFile(atPath: path.absoluteString, contents: data, attributes: nil)
} catch {
  // handle error
}
```

I have not gotten any errors or exceptions. It runs perfectly. But I can't see that file. Where can I find that file?

Comment: What do you mean by see it? It's in your app's sandbox, so you can only view it through Xcode (I believe at least: in devices, view the app's container), or by opening the file in your code and performing some action on it.

Answer (score 0):

just add in **target -> info -> custom iOS Target properties**

*Application supports iTunes file sharing* - YES
and you will be able to see the folder you saved a file in **Files app** on your simulator.

Otherwise use `print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask))` to get a path to folder using **Finder**